# Adding a product to Magento via PHP API results in some attributes not being set

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.6

I am trying to write a script to transfer some products from a list of products in a MySQL DB into a Magento 1.6.2 store. I have the following code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setWebsiteId("2");
$product->setName($row['name']);
$product->setDescription('No Description');
$product->setShortDescription('No Description');
$product->setAttributeSetId(4); // need to look this up
$product->setSku($sku); 
if (isset($row['price'])) $product->setPrice($row['price']);
if (isset($row['msrp'])) $product->setMsrp($row['msrp']);
$product->setCategoryId($map_mysql_cat_to_mage_cat[$row['category_id']]);
$product->setWeight($weight);
$product->setManufacturer($row['manufacturer']);
$product->setTaxClassId(2); // taxable goods
$product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search
$product->setStatus(1); // enabled

// assign product to the default website
echo "Adding Product...";
$product->save();
echo "Product Added." . PHP_EOL;
```

This results in the product successfully adding to the Magento catalog, and the name, SKU, price, MSRP, and weight being set correctly.

However, the Manufacturer attribute, category, and website remain unset/empty. $row['manufacturer'] is definitely a valid, non-empty string, and $map_mysql_cat_to_mage_cat[$row['category_id']] resolves to an integer, which matches a valid category id.

Where am I going wrong, I'm tearing my hair out!

Comment: Shouldn't this be `setCategoryIds` (plural, not singular)?

Comment: And `setWebsiteIds` should be plural, too, IIRC.

Comment: I tried it originally with `setCategoryIds()` and `setWebsiteIds()`, but that did not work either.

Comment: I've tried again, with `setCategoryIds()` and `setWebsiteIds()`, and ensured that a string gets passed as a category rather than an int, by using the following: `$product->setCategoryIds("" . $map_mysql_cat_to_mage_cat[$row['category_id']]);`. It is now working - but I have changed other things in Magento in the mean time, so it could have been some of the other changes I have made that resulted in the code working.